# init.d and remote files systems

Tags: linux, init.d

The [Linux Standard Base Core Specification, 22.4. Installation and Removal of Init Scripts](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initsrcinstrm.html) says:

> An init script shall be installed in /etc/init.d (which may be a
> symbolic link to another location), by the package installer.

We have a situation which as as result of corporate policy and the standard VM configurations, we are not able to install third-party apps using the standard package installers (yum/rpm) or to the default locations (/opt, etc.). Instead, apps must be installed in an NFS mounted partition (/apps), requiring `remote_fs`. We use still init.d to manage stop/start.

Related question that does not provide clarity: [Linux's /etc/init.d - symlink, hard link, or actual file?](https://serverfault.com/q/718139/189417)

There are 2 options, both with issues:

- Add wrapper file to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`. This can be an issue if the third-party updates the wrapper (happens often enough) and we forget to update the init.d copy.
- Place a sym-link from `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` to the target file    (`/etc/rc.d/init.d/myapp -> /apps/myapp/bin/wrapper`).

Second option presents an issue as, even though the wrapper says:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $remote_fs $syslog $time
```

There is strong likelihood the required `remote_fs` is not yet been available upon starting, so the file pointed to by sym-link is not available to read the INIT INFO block expecting `remote_fs` and other services from (catch-22). The following error is reported upon startup (ps: `/etc/init.d -> rc.d/init.d`):

```
systemd-sysv-generator[509]: stat() failed on /etc/rc.d/init.d/myapp: No such file or directory
```

**I can't be the first one to face this problem but could not find a best practice recommendation**.

I am considering implementing the following workaround; would like to know if there are unknown consequences I am not aware of. Instead of a sym-link, create a "dummy" or "pass-thru" wrapper at `/etc/rc.d/init.d/myapp`.

```
# chkconfig:         345 75 15
# description:       myapp
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $remote_fs $syslog $time
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $remote_fs $syslog $time
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: App Description
### END INIT INFO

/apps/myapp/bin/wrapper "$@"
```

Seems to work fine in terms of stop/start, etc. Not likely to change (ever ?), unlike the working part of the wrapper.

**Anything I've overlooked or not considered**?

Comment: Fixing the corporate policy should be your top priority.

Comment: You're funny. You evidently never worked for a Corporation. I'd end up retiring before getting the policies changed! I'm still on track to retire before the mainframe!